# command line compiling generates bigger file than the online version

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am testing google closure compiler on command line.
I took the latest version :

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --version
Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20190618
Built on: 2019-06-21 17:24
```

I am generating a compressed version of my javascript like this :

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar my_script.js > out.js
```

The problem is that the generated code is bigger than the one I get when I use the online service at https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

I noticed that the command line version added, at the beginning, the following code :

```
var $jscomp=$jscomp||{};$jscomp.scope={};$jscomp.findInternal=function(a,c,b){a instanceof String&&(a=String(a));for(var d=a.length,e=0;e<d;e++){var f=a[e];if(c.call(b,f,e,a))return{i:e,v:f}}return{i:-1,v:void 0}};$jscomp.ASSUME_ES5=!1;$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_MAP=!1;$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_SET=!1;$jscomp.SIMPLE_FROUND_POLYFILL=!1;
$jscomp.defineProperty=$jscomp.ASSUME_ES5||"function"==typeof Object.defineProperties?Object.defineProperty:function(a,c,b){a!=Array.prototype&&a!=Object.prototype&&(a[c]=b.value)};$jscomp.getGlobal=function(a){return"undefined"!=typeof window&&window===a?a:"undefined"!=typeof global&&null!=global?global:a};$jscomp.global=$jscomp.getGlobal(this);
$jscomp.polyfill=function(a,c,b,d){if(c){b=$jscomp.global;a=a.split(".");for(d=0;d<a.length-1;d++){var e=a[d];e in b||(b[e]={});b=b[e]}a=a[a.length-1];d=b[a];c=c(d);c!=d&&null!=c&&$jscomp.defineProperty(b,a,{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:c})}};$jscomp.polyfill("Array.prototype.find",function(a){return a?a:function(a,b){return $jscomp.findInternal(this,a,b).v}},"es6","es3");
```

I do not have such a code in my script: Where does it come from ? 
how can I produce the same output as the online version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the compiler command line work as the web service, I just added an option :

```
--language_out=ECMASCRIPT_2015
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a discrepancy between the settings on the web service and the ones you're using locally.

Have a look at a [Closure Compiler: Flags and Options](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options) to see what settings you might prefer.

If you'd share your source, it'd be possible to try and help you narrow down the options.

As for the extra code, I believe it is at least partially a polyfill for `Array.prototype.find` (aka `[].find`), which I assume *is* in your code?

If so, that's Closure injecting code to improve your cross browser compatibility.